# Show that while calculating partial traces the probability is independent of the basis of one of the measurements

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix, linear-algebra

Consider calculating the probability of the outcome m alone of some composite system $AB$.

$p_A(m) = \sum_{n=0}^{d_B-1} p_{AB}(m,n) $

$=  \sum_{n=0}^{d_B-1}(⟨α_m|⊗⟨β_n|)\rho_{AB}(|α_m⟩⊗|β_n⟩)$

I'm trying to show that this value is independent of the basis $\{|β_n|, n = 0, 1, . . . , d_{B-1}\}$ (so we can just replace it with the computational basis for example.

I know that I've to use the no signalling theorem for it, and will have to decompose the density matrix $\rho_{AB}$ into $\sum_i p_i |\psi_i⟩⟨\psi_i|$ but beyond that I haven't made much progress